# Fade DIV out / in during CSS media query

Tags: css, css-animations

My goal is to fade the `.container` content during a window re-size at widths of 1400, 1600, and 1800 pixels. Currently the animation will only fire once at the 1400 mark and none of the others.

Ultimately I would prefer `.container` to fade out and back in during those re-size events to provide a nice UI experience. I'm not entirely sure if this can be accomplished with CSS alone, or whether this will need some JS as well...

```
.container
{
    width: 1225px;
    left: -2px;
    padding-top: 275px;
    padding-left: 37px;
    position: relative;

}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
.container
{
    width: 1375px;
    left: -60px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeonresize 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
.container
{
    width: 1575px;
    left: -140px;
    padding-top: 272px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeonresize 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
.container
{
    width: 1800px;
    left: -260px;
    padding-left: 36px;
    padding-top: 285px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeonresize 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeonresize { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
```

Comment: the media query fires only once because the ordering of the queries is incorrect , reverse the order and it will fire thrice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because after the animation is run once, at any breakpoint, it will not run it again, as it is already a CSS property and no change happens to that between breakpoints. Since there is no repeat set for your animation, it only runs the first time it encounters the animation. Try setting three different animations like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
.container
{
    width: 1375px;
    left: -60px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeonresize1 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
.container
{
    width: 1575px;
    left: -140px;
    padding-top: 272px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeonresize2 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
.container
{
    width: 1800px;
    left: -260px;
    padding-left: 36px;
    padding-top: 285px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeonresize3 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeonresize1 { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeonresize2 { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeonresize3 { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
```

Comment: Great! This gets me closer to what I want to achieve. I just realized that this will still fire on page load and not just on re-size. Care to provide an example that will only animate on re-size? I understand if this is outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: Considering that CSS media queries are fired whenever the screen dimensions match, I doubt if it would be possible to do it in just CSS alone. You could use javascript and use the window.onresize() method if you would like to achieve that.